# Customising error fields for Django log in templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm semi-new to Django (but not new to Python or front end languages) - I'm just having a little trouble rendering required fields and error messages.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        if username and not password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid password...")
        elif not username and password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("I think you've forgotten to enter your username...")
        elif username and password:
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist...")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password...")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not appear to be active.")

        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

login_form.html:

```
    <form class="contact-form contact-form-two" name="contact-form" method="POST" action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="User ID">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='{{ title }}'>Sign In</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Ignore the classes - I'm just borrowing from the default contact form I have created (at some point I will reorganise into one master "form" class.)

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login, logout

from .forms import UserLoginForm

# Create your views here.

def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    title = "login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        #Display the redirect if the form was valid and if user authentication was successful:
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())

    return render(request, "blog/user_auth/login_form.html", { "form": form, "title": title })
```

Essentially, could anyone point me in the right direction for rendering the raised error messages that I have created within the template html?

The only examples online use pre-rendered django form html using the `{{ form.as_p }}` tag.

Any pro-tips on how to render these raised validation errors within the login_form would be gladly accepted!

Comment: Start here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#more-granular-output

Comment: @theWanderer4865 With what I've set up, can I do a for loop - for field in forms then pass in field.errors and field.label_tag to my pre-rendered HTML?

Comment: I wouldn't, it stinks having to write it all out (maybe look at Crispy forms?) but you'll thank yourself when you have a designer/ need to tweak one element to or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can show form error in your login template like this

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-error">
  <h4>Please fix the following errors</h4>
  <ul>
    {% for field in form %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <li><a href="#id_{{ field.name }}" class="error">{{ error|escape }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hmmm....not sure this is sufficient. It looks ok - except for the for loop within a for loop, this might render two errors instead of one. Also - there doesn't seem to be error handling? So, I think it will just spit out that both the form fields are required without taking into account my raised errors. Thank you for the attempt - I think I might be able to use this as a launch pad.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts 1st loop for error field and 2nd loop for number of error for each field.
Suppose, if you have password field and that has some condition like 
1. password need to 8 character 
2. pass should have one capital letter
then it will show both error
if you don't use 2nd loop then you will have to use index of field.errors